# 値が空白の時でもエラーが出ないようにしたい

Tags: ruby, json

jsonでgetpositionsの"size"の値を取り出して認識させたいのですが、そのgetpositionsの値が空白の時エラーになってしまって、プログラムが止まってしまします。
値が空白の時は0にしてエラーを回避するプログラムを書きたいのですがうまくいきません。。どうかよろしくお願いします。

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "openssl"
require "json"

key = "kkkkkkkk"
secret = "kkkkkkkkk"

timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
method = "GET"
uri = URI.parse("kkkkkkkkkkkk")
uri.path = "/v1/me/getpositions"
uri.query = "product_code=kkkkkkkkkk"

text = timestamp + method + uri.request_uri
sign = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256"), secret, text)

options = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {
                             "ACCESS-KEY" => key,
                             "ACCESS-TIMESTAMP" => timestamp,
                             "ACCESS-SIGN" => sign,
                             });

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
response = https.request(options)

json = response.body
getpositions = JSON.parse(json)
getpositions || (getpositions = 0)
puts getpositions[0]["size"]        # ここに値が入ってないとエラーになります。
```

エラーコード

```
size.rb:31:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、空文字のjson(`[]`や`{}`)は、`||`演算子では`true`に判定されるため、

```
getpositions || (getpositions = 0)
```

のコードでは、0は代入されず`[]`のままです。

この時、`getpositions[0]`とすると`nil`が取得されるため、`["size"]`にアクセスした時、ご提示のエラーとなります。

もし、`getpositions`に0を代入したとしても、0に対して`["size"]`を取得することになるため、こちらもエラーとなります。

ですので、以下のように、三項演算子等で`getpositions`が空かどうかをチェックして`["size"]`にアクセスすると良いかと思います。

```
json = response.body
getpositions = JSON.parse(json)
puts getpositions.empty? ? 0 : getpositions[0]["size"]
```

Answer (score 1):

空のjson配列でもエラーなしで値をとる(値がない場合はnil)のは dig を使えば可能です。

```
getpositions = []
puts getpositions.dig(0, "size") || 0
```

(Ruby 2.3 以上が必要です。)

Comment: こちらも参考になると思います。
https://qiita.com/vzvu3k6k/items/1705c7f4b29c08787ea0

Answer (score 0):

単に `getpositions[0]` が `nil` のときの初期値を設定したいということであれば、`||=` を使うのはいかがですか？

```
# 配列先頭のハッシュの "size" キーに対応する値があればそのまま、未定義・nil・false なら 0 が代入される。
getpositions[0]["size"] ||= 0
```